# Duplicate data - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I am using jdbc to grab data from SQL, and it works, kind of.
I have default index XXXXXX but from database i want to create a new index.

```
output {
 if [type] == "stops" or [type] == "signon"  {
   elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    ilm_rollover_alias => "WWWW"
 }
}
else{
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    ilm_rollover_alias => "ZZZZ"
}
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }   
}
```

In kibana i see that i have index WWWW and ZZZZ, but the same data i get in my default index XXXX, how to do to get data only to WWWW and ZZZZ ?

Comment: This is your full output config? Where do your XXXX index comes from? Update your question with our full logstash pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to edit my questions so i will write it here. I solve it, i found that elasticsearch **MERGE** config file, due to my conditions (if and else) did not work correctly. After I changed my conditions everything work fine.